# Extracting data from PDF files using python

Tags: python

New to python here, and I have a challenge which is to extract order information presented in a PDF file. I can log onto the website to convert the orders onto PDF, however what I require is to export it into excel in the form of a table.

The columns required are order number, order date,  code, items, quantity, price , total

The PDF file has multiple pages and the way the order date/order number is presented its within a different section, for every order the code should extract the last order date / order no at the top of the page.

An example of what the PDF pages looks like can be found below, there are multiple pages on the file. The output that I am looking for can be seen below. I have contacted the company and they do not have API's that can be exposed.

[image: Invoice sample]

[image: Sample of what the python code should output]

Comment: I have made enquiries and they do not have API's exposed, question updated.

Comment: What have searches for something like "pdf programmatically extract table" resulted in?

Comment: Look into the `tabula` module. Try something like: `data = tabula.read_pdf(path, multiple_tables=True, pages=[1,2], columns=[1,2,3])`. I also recomend doing stuff like this in Jupyter so you have immediate feedback to your code since stuff like this requires a lot of tweaking around. Then use e.g. pandas to create the table you want and export it to csv or excel...

Comment: is the information displayed on the website as well? What about directly scraping it from there via [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?